# has_one belongs_to relationship issue in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I am having a problem with relationships in Rails 4.

There are 4 models

1. User
2. Request
3. Make
4. Models

A User has_many Requests, a Request has_one Make and a Make has_many Models.

The User->Requests and Make->Models has_many relationships are fine but the Request->Make has_one relationship is failing.

```
class Request < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    has_one :make
end

class Make < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :models
  belongs_to :request
end
```

The Schemas for each model are...

```
create_table "requests", force: true do |t|
  t.integer  "user_id"
  t.integer  "make_id"
  t.datetime "created_at"
  t.datetime "updated_at"
end

create_table "makes", force: true do |t|
  t.string   "name"
  t.datetime "created_at"
  t.datetime "updated_at"
end
```

When I try to assign a Make to a Request I get the following error

```
Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'makes.request_id' in 'where clause': SELECT  `makes`.* FROM `makes`  WHERE `makes`.`request_id` = 7 LIMIT 1                                                                           
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid Exception: Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'makes.request_id' in 'where clause': SELECT  `makes`.* FROM `makes`  WHERE `makes`.`request_id` = 7 LIMIT 1                                 
nil
```

Why is ActiveRecord requiring a request_id in Make?  Wouldn't that only be applicable for a has_many relationship as I have in the User->Requests and Makes->Models relationships?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `has_one` and `belongs_to` methods allow you to create **one-to-one** associations between your models, therefore allowing you to easily access each other through various helper methods.

`has_one` should only be used if the other class contains the "foreign key". If the current class contains the "foreign key", you should use `belongs_to` instead.

Based on the schema you provided, the associations should be defined like in the following example:

```
class Request < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Because you have a `make_id` column in the "requests" table.
  belongs_to :make
end

class Make < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Because the Request model has the "foreign key" that 
  # creates the association, in this case `make_id`.
  has_one :request
end
```

By making the associations like in the example above, Rails will provide you with helper methods that allow you to access or create each associated model:

```
# Request Model
@request = Request.create!

# Helper methods to access `make`: make, build_make, create_make, make=
@request.make
@request.build_make
@request.create_make
@request.make = Make.create!
# ...


# Make Model
@make = Make.create!

# Helper methods to access `request`
@make.request
@make.build_request
@make.create_request
@make.request = Request.create!
#...
```

We use the `has_one` and `belongs_to` methods to create the associations, but also to have access to all the helper methods that Rails creates for us. Depending on whether you want to access **Make** from **Request** or the other way around, you could add or remove the **has_one** or **belongs_to** from a particular class.

By keeping each one in both classes though, we get access to a bunch of helper methods from both sides. If for example you removed the `belongs_to :make` from Request, you wouldn't be able to access **make** from Request with `@request.make`. However, you can still access Request from make with `@make.request` as long as you keep the **has_one** method.

Remember that migrations are their own thing and we need to setup the associations on the Database level as well by adding the "foreign key" to the correct table. We can easily figure out where to add the foreign key by looking at the definitions of **has_one** and **belongs_to**. **has_one** says that the "foreign key" should be in the associated table, and **belongs_to** says it should be in **this** table.

I hope that helps! There is some more information here:

- http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods/belongs_to
- http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods/has_one

Comment: Thanks for your help!  You were correct as the association was around the wrong way.  I was looking for a one to many relationship so I have has_many on the Make side instead of has_one.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your schema and the error message there appears to be no foreign key from `requests` in `makes`.

See this, for example:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-one-association

There, Supplier has one Account, and `accounts` has a `supplier_id`. Check out the corresponding migration example.

Answer (score 0):

You probably just need to add the request_id column to your makes table.

Run:

```
rails g migration add_request_id_to_makes request_id:integer


bundle exec rake db:migrate
```